# Связать узлы одного уровня в бинарном дереве

Tags: c#

Добрый день. 
Есть задание, связать узлы одного уровня в бинарном дереве.

Например есть дерево

```
     1
    / \
   2   3
  /   / \
 4   5   6
```

В результате нужно получить

```
     1
    / \
   2-> 3
  /   / \
 4-> 5-> 6
```

Реализовываю так :

```
class Node
    {
        public int n;
        public Node left;
        public Node right;
        public Node level;
    }

class Program
    {
        /* Set next right of all descendents of tree.
        Assumption:  tree is a compete binary tree */
        private static void ConnectRecur(Node tree)
        {
            if (tree == null)
                return;

            // Set the level pointer for tree left child
            if (tree.left !=null)
            {
                tree.left.level = tree.right;
            }

            // Set the level pointer for tree right child
            // tree.level will be NULL if tree is the right most child at its level
            if (tree.right !=null)
            {
                tree.right.level = (tree.level !=null) ? tree.level.left : null;
            }

            // Set level for other nodes 
            ConnectRecur(tree.left);
            ConnectRecur(tree.right);
        }

        // Sets the level of root and calls ConnectRecur() for other nodes
        private static void Connect(Node tree)
        {
            // Set the level for root
            tree.level = null;

            // Set the next right for rest of the nodes (other than root)
            ConnectRecur(tree);
        }

        /* Helper function that allocates a new node with the
           given data and NULL left and right pointers. */
        private static Node NewNode(int data)
        {
            Node node = new Node
                {
                    n = data, 
                    left = null, 
                    right = null, 
                    level = null
                };

            return (node);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Node root = NewNode(1);
            root.left = NewNode(2);
            root.right = NewNode(3);
            root.left.left = NewNode(4);
            root.right.left = NewNode(5);
            root.right.right = NewNode(6);
            // Populates level pointer in all nodes
            Connect(root);

            // Check the values of levels pointers
            Console.Write("Following are populated levels pointers in the tree " + "(-1 is printed if there is no level) \n");
            Console.Write("Level of {0:D} is {1:D} \n", root.n, (root.level != null) ? root.level.n : -1);
            Console.Write("Level of {0:D} is {1:D} \n", root.left.n, (root.left.level != null) ? root.left.level.n : -1);
            Console.Write("Level of {0:D} is {1:D} \n", root.right.n, (root.right.level != null) ? root.right.level.n : -1);
            Console.Write("Level of {0:D} is {1:D} \n", root.left.left.n, (root.left.left.level != null) ? root.left.left.level.n : -1);
            Console.Write("Level of {0:D} is {1:D} \n", root.right.left.n, (root.right.left.level != null) ? root.right.left.level.n : -1);
            Console.Write("Level of {0:D} is {1:D} \n", root.right.right.n, (root.right.right.level != null) ? root.right.right.level.n : -1);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

Вопрос: 
Правильно ли я делаю и есть ли более правильные реализации этого задания?

Спасибо.

Comment: А что будет, если, например, у узла 2 будут два потомка? Я не слишком внимательно просмотрел ваш код, но мне кажется, что ваша программа заменит правого потомка и, таким образом, выкинет всё текущее правое поддерево узла 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код

```
if (tree.left !=null)
{
    tree.left.level = tree.right;
}
```

неверен: ведь правое поддерево может быть пустым. Кроме того, и у `tree.level` левое, а то и правое поддерево может быть пустым.

Сама идея рекурсивного заполнения правильна, но мне кажется, заполнять легче справа налево.

```
class HorizontalConnector
{
    List<Node> currentLastOnLevel = new List<Node>();

    void ensureLevel(int level)
    {
        while (level >= currentLastOnLevel.Count)
            currentLastOnLevel.Add(null);
    }

    private HorizontalConnector() {}

    static public void Connect(Node root)
    {
        new HorizontalConnector().ConnectRec(root, 0);
    }

    void ConnectRec(Node curr, int depth)
    {
        if (curr == null) return;

        ensureLevel(depth);
        curr.level = currentLastOnLevel[depth];
        currentLastOnLevel[depth] = curr;

        ConnectRec(curr.right, depth + 1);
        ConnectRec(curr.left, depth + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Там же есть в коде есть `"Assumption: tree is a compete binary tree."`

Comment: @Котик: И правда. Но тогда рисунок не вполне верен, и проверки на null вовсе не нужны.

---
Ах да, нужны на нижнем уровне.

Comment: Набросал вариант, который должен работать с любым деревом.

Answer (score 1):

Ну и для Java:

```
LinkedList<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
queue.push(t);
queue.push(null);

Node prevNode = null;
while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
    Node node = queue.pollLast();

    if (node != null) {
        if (node.left != null) {
            queue.push(node.left);
        }
        if (node.right != null) {
            queue.push(node.right);
        }
    } else if (!queue.isEmpty()){
        queue.push(null);
    }

    if (prevNode != null) {
        prevNode.level = node;
    }
    prevNode = node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой вариант на С++ без дополнительных списков и оптимизирован по скорости

```
// recursive function for link nodes at the same level

void linkSameLevel(struct node *t)
{

    // declare local variables
    node *upCurrent = t;
    node *downFirst = 0;
    node *downCurrent = 0;

    if(!t)
        return;

    // doing iteration through the one level for upNode node
    // initialize "level" value for next level
    for(;;)
    {
        // checking left branch
        if(downCurrent && upCurrent->left)
        {
            downCurrent->level = upCurrent->left;
            downCurrent = upCurrent->left;
        }
        else if(!downCurrent && upCurrent->left)
            downCurrent = upCurrent->left;

        if(!downFirst && downCurrent && (downCurrent->left || downCurrent->right))
            downFirst = downCurrent;


        // checking right branch
        if(downCurrent && upCurrent->right)
        {
            downCurrent->level = upCurrent->right;
            downCurrent = upCurrent->right;
        }
        else if(!downCurrent && upCurrent->right)
            downCurrent = upCurrent->right;

        if(!downFirst && downCurrent && (downCurrent->left || downCurrent->right))
            downFirst = downCurrent;

        if(upCurrent->level)
            upCurrent = upCurrent->level;
        else
            break;
    }

    if(downFirst)
        linkSameLevel(downFirst);
}
```

Comment: Ну, а где же изящество, почему миллион проверок и гора кода? Вот вам ваша же идея в другом оформлении: <http://pastebin.com/h4P9JacM>. Без дополнительных списков и рекурсии.

Answer (score 0):

А если так? Куда короче )

Objective-C

```
@interface Node : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger n;
@property (nonatomic) Node *left;
@property (nonatomic) Node *right;
@property (nonatomic) Node *level;
@end
void linkSameLevel(Node* node)
{
    if (!node) return;
    node.left.level = node.right?node.right:node.level.left?node.level.left:node.level.right;
    node.right.level = node.level.left?node.level.left:node.level.right;

    if (node.level) linkSameLevel(node.level);
    if (node.left) linkSameLevel(node.left);
    if (node.right) linkSameLevel(node.right);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, аккуратно оформляйте код ответа. Это увеличит ценность вашего ответа для других.